# When and where was Zilpha McCubbin from Missouri born?

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records

The records I have state Zilpha McCubbin from Missouri migrated west to Oregon in 1852, married my great, great, grandfather William J Funk formerly from Marietta Ohio. They were married in 1867 in Portland Oregon. They went back to Kansas in 1870 for ten years, moved back to Portland, then settled in Walowa County Oregon, Enterprise area.  I do not have any information about Zilpha (McCubbin) Funk other than that.

How can I find out when and where she was born, and who her parents were, to understand  where this part of the McCubbin family came from?

Comment: Scott, thanks for your question. I've tidied it up a little to make it focus more tightly on Zilpha's birth records, which should get you a better answer.  Do you have an approximate date of birth for Zilpha?it looks like she's in Rock Creek Kansas in the 1880 census aged 28 which makes her birth circa 1852 -- can you confirm this is her? Ditto for the 1870 census, where she's enumerated as Jane Z. Funk in Portland aged 19.

Comment: Do I have good news for you! My husband is also a great grandson of Zilpha and William Funk!
We even have a wonderful picture of them, and 2 of their sons... James A Funk & Mertie Jewell are the grandparents of my husband Alan. I have done a lot of research and have a whole folder about them, and a family biography that was written by James, which includes names and some info about Zilpha's siblings and parents..... it is full of rich information. Please contact us via my profile.

Comment: @AnnetteMcIsaac I think you should write an Answer rather than just a Comment

Answer (score 5):

In the 1860 census of Jacksonville, Jackson, Oregon Zilpha J. McCubby age 9 born Missouri is enumerated with her parents A. McCubby age 42 born Kentucky and Sarah McCubby age 31 born Missouri. The eldest child present is Jno. B. McCubby born circa 1847 in Missouri.

[Note: I found this by doing a fuzzy search on the first name and surname -- any first name beginning with Z and any surname beginning with M. I chose the 1860 census because it was the first in which Zilpha would appear and she would very likely be with her parents.]

In the 1850 census of Abraham McCubbin age 33 born Kentucky and Sarah McCubbin age 21 born Missouri are resident in Miller County, Missouri, with a number of children including their eldest John age 3 born Missouri.

[Note: This was the first census in which Jno. B born circa 1847 would appear -- again, he would very likely be with his parents.]

I would be cautiously confident that Zilpha's parents are Abraham McCubbin and Sarah; however, I have not confirmed without a doubt that there are no other candidates in the relevant censuses.

An Idaho death certificate from March 1922 for Leander Pleasant McCubbin names his parents as Abraham McCubbin and Sarah Dean; it is noteworthy that in the 1850 census there are 3 young individuals named Jane Dean (19), Jacob Dean (15) and Perry Dean (15) in the household of Alexander McCubbin and his wife Sarah.

Sources:

- Indexed transcriptions of the 1860 US census are available at
  familysearch.org; I am not aware of any free source of the images but
  ancestry.com and findmypast.com both have them available under their
  relevant subscription.
- The 1850 US census is searchable with viewable images at familysearch.org.
- FamilySearch.org has indexed Idaho Death Certificates 1911-1937.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.  I have a three volumn hard bound books that are "The Centenial History of Oregon".  Dated 1811 to 1911 that most likely were my great grandparents.  My Grand Father had them, and my mom gave them to me.  In the second edition it just states Zilpha McCubbin crossed the plains with her parents 1852 when she was a "young girl".  The books were published in 1912.  Thank you again for the information and the sources to look further !

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl -- images for some US Federal censuses are available for free via Heritage Quest, which is now a ProQuest database http://proquest.libguides.com/heritagequest .  Readers in the US should check with their local public libraries to see if their library subscribes.  About.com has a review of the collection here: http://genealogy.about.com/cs/census/gr/heritage_quest.htm . The last time I used HQ, the 1930 was not complete, but it's a good alternate source of census images, especially when Ancestry.com's image is blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Zilpha's Father- Abraham McCubbin, born in Miller Missouri, 5/21,1817- died 3/12/1882 
Abrahams parents were John McCubbin and Elizabeth(Lemmon)
Abraham has been previously married, but when he came out to Oregon(from Indiana?) to visit his parent's; while visiting, he got word that his wife and children had suddenly died of an illness. He stayed in Oregon.

Zilpha's Mother- Sarah (Dean)McCubbin, born in Kentucky, 5/24/1829- died 4/4/1897
I have not been able to discover Sarah's parents.
Zilpha had 2 brothers John and Leander, and 2 sisters Margaret and Melvina.
You can google "Leander McCubbin" and see an article written about him.

Zilpha and William J Funk owned the W.J.Funk & Sons Mercantile in 1904 in Enterprise Oregon.
Their sons James A., and Charles E.helped him run the store. After operating the store for several years, the store was sold, and the boys went into the sheep business.
 The building still stands, and we were able to visit it in Enterprise 2 years ago. Their is a wonderful photo of them hanging in the museum in Joseph Oregon(near Enterprise).
 We have a biography written by James A, great grandfather to my husband.
I have found a lot of information on the net, by googling all the family names, and patiently going through many searches.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy.SE! Where there any particular strategies that helped you find this information?